# What are the IEC IP standards/code for electric vehicles?

Tags: electrical-engineering, electric-vehicles

What an end consumer should know about the level of IP protection provided for a vehicle against hazards which include but not limited to environmental factors, thermal runaway in batteries, etc.

Comment: The IP codes in ICE 60529 only relate to dust and liquid ingress. For more general safety standards for electric vehicles, see for example https://www.iso.org/ics/43.120/x/ or an equivalent national standards organization.

Comment: @alephzero That is indeed a very informative resource, right from the ISO! Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

Best open-access resources for EV electrical safety requirements are the American FMVSS 305:

https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/49/571.305

and the European UNECE rule 100:

https://op.europa.eu/en/publication-detail/-/publication/fd8e6b47-d767-11e4-9de8-01aa75ed71a1/language-en

The requirements are quite similar and car makers usually design the vehicles to fill both the requirements. In the ISO and IEC standards are more accurate requirements, but the standards cost like couple of hundreds of dollars per standard (unless your university or company library has a mass license).

Following the standards is not mandatory but usually the easiest way to fulfill the legal requirements (FMVSS 305 and UNECE 100).